# Pyinstaller WARNING: Library user32 required via ctypes not found

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

When I compile my project using pyinstaller, I get these random error codes and warning for some ctype library module not found. How can I suppress these warnings? This is called in docker environment set to UBUNTU 18.04.

As per this discussion in pyinstaller, there is no plan to add a fix for this warning. So, trying to see if I can suppress this warning.
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1403

```
6693 WARNING: Library user32 required via ctypes not found
6558 WARNING: Library user32 required via ctypes not found
6728 WARNING: Library user32 required via ctypes not found
6304 WARNING: Library user32 required via ctypes not found
```

pyinstaller doesn't find ctypes library.